# WaterFox, what does this errror mean?

Tags: windows-8.1, waterfox

Today when my browser was loading MyAnimelist.Net I got this error:

```
XML Parsing error: unexpectec parser state
```

[image]

I only have issue with Mal today, but my question is what does it mean, & is the issue with my PC stuff (maybe something in my PC interrupts connection with Mal?) or is the problem with the page, something like this has happened before with another page a week ago, Mal does seem to lag a bit, but this message makes it seem like its browser fault/problem, it probably goes away by next time i turn PC on, but if it is PC or Browser issue, then how to fix it, or can't it be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML error is associated with the browser and not with your PC. To overcome this issue, reset the browser to its factory settings. If you see this error even after resetting the browser, then do a clean reinstall after completely removing Firefox from your machine.

Comment: But i had problems with MyAnimelist.Net (other sites were & are okay, no issues), slow loading & lagging, like when i write a comment there it takes few minutes when my written post appears, can XML error cause a problem with just one site? or is it the site issue & Browser takes it as its own issue/problem? in other words false positive, & last time i got that error with another site was a week ago, 100% clean reinstall is not possible, cause PC always remembers something no matter how clean job u do some settings & problems remain, unless u reinstall hole windows

Comment: i had issues with chrome what could not be fixed  (thats why i got firefox & then waterfox cause i had problems with videos in firefox), it had issues with my system i guess, i did clean reinstall with chrome & there were things that were not like when i installed it first time, & i did chose remove user data & settings when i uninstalled it

Comment: to ask it simply, can i get the XML error then to if there are problems with the site itself (or when the site is under attack) & not my browser?

Comment: if the xml files from the network cannot be processed by the browser, i mean both the site and your browser, you can experience such problem. This problem occurs on a rare scenario either any issues related to the website or the file processed for the website remains unprocessed. It is definitely not the issue with your PC.

Comment: got it, not PC, BDW by PC i meant Win own security & internet security, but can this error be caused by issues with sites itself to? & i should not pother with it unless it becomes awry day event with all pages?